# QGIS Clip to Hemisphere plugin giving 'NoneType' error

Tags: qgis, clip

I'd like to use the Clip to Hemisphere plugin in QGIS to reduce artifacts generated by my Orthographic Projection.

I'm using a custom CRS:

+proj=ortho +lat_0=70.6632 +lon_0=23.6817 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs

with a Natural Earth admin shapefile

When I load the plugin, I enter lat and lon, click run, select my custom CRS and get the following error:

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'difference' See log for more detail.

The layer generated clips to random countries instead of clipping the hemisphere like I would like [image]

Comment: Strangely, it works for me. Does it help if you remove the ne_admin layer, and use `Save As ...` to another file name and your custom CRS?

Comment: Thank you AndreJ. I think the problem was my very old version of QGIS. I also should have been using the plugin before reprojecting to Orthographic, using straight WSG 82, then Orthographic

Comment: There is now a [new version of the Clip to Hemisphere plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ClipToHemisphere/version/0.3/), which will  generate a warning if it's used on a non-WGS84 layer.